# How can I reduce the log file of my thesis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm using pgfplots to plot several plots throughout my thesis, and I'm about half way and already the editor is having issues with loading the log file.
Can anyone suggest a way I can reduce this?
The error I get is "coordinate (,) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter. (see also unbounded coords=jump)."
All my plots are added using pgfplots, so I really don't want to go back and import them as images (particularly because they wont look quite as good!). I'm using TeXstudio
Here is a sample of the code for one of my plots;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ytick pos=left,xtick pos=left,
    %title=Particle size variation as a func. of CTA concentration,
    xlabel = $\dot{\gamma}$,
    ylabel = $\eta$,
    y unit=\si{\pascal\second},
    x unit=\si{\second^{-1}},
    %ymin=55,
    %ymax=70,
      ymode=log,
        log ticks with fixed point,
      xmode=log,
        log ticks with fixed point,
        % for log axes, x filter operates on LOGS.
        % and log(x * 1000) = log(x) + log(1000):
        %x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1 + 6.90775527898214},
    legend style={draw=none},legend pos = outer north east, %outer if you like
    %width=300,height=280,
    width=340,height=230,
    %axis lines=left,
    enlargelimits=.1 % <- adds 10% of the axis range on both sides
    ]
    \addplot[only marks,mark = *,mark size=2,]table [x=B18x,y=B18y,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addlegendentry{15 vol\%}
    \addplot[only marks,mark = diamond*,blue,mark size=2,]table [x=B16x,y=B16y,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addlegendentry{14 vol\%}
    \addplot[only marks,mark = triangle*,green,mark size=2,]table [x=B14x,y=B14y,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addlegendentry{12 vol\%}
    \addplot[only marks,mark = pentagon*,yellow,mark size=2,]table [x=B10x,y=B10y,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addlegendentry{8 vol\%}
    \addplot[only marks,mark = asterisk,orange,mark size=2,]table [x=B6x,y=B6y,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addlegendentry{5 vol\%}
    \addplot[only marks,mark = +,red,mark size=2,]table [x=B2x,y=B2y,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addlegendentry{2 vol\%}
    \addplot[only marks,mark = o,mark size=2,]table [x=B18xh,y=B18yh,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[only marks,mark = diamond,blue,mark size=2,]table [x=B16xh,y=B16yh,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[only marks,mark = triangle,green,mark size=2,]table [x=B14xh,y=B14yh,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[only marks,mark = pentagon,yellow,mark size=2,]table [x=B10xh,y=B10yh,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[only marks,mark = star,orange,mark size=2,]table [x=B6xh,y=B6yh,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[only marks,mark = x,red,mark size=2,]table [x=B2xh,y=B2yh,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:4]table [x=B18xc,y=B18yc,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:4]table [x=B16xc,y=B16yc,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:4]table [x=B14xc,y=B14yc,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:4]table [x=B10xc,y=B10yc,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:4]table [x=B6xc,y=B6yc,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:4]table [x=B2xc,y=B2yc,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[only marks,mark = x,orange,mark size=2,]table [x=B1x,y=B1y,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:4]table [x=B1xc,y=B1yc,col sep=comma,]{barea.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Bare}
    \label{fig:Bare}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Is there anyway to work around this issue? Please excuse me if this is a silly question - I'm relatively new to latex!

[Link to csv file I use for this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AivKDSH3EHjbgYdg8N1KrN4E4SN9pw)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can import them a `pdf` images to have the same quality.

Comment: It is not possible to run your document as posted,  what is in the log file that is making it large?

Comment: How many images do you have?  I have a ~1,000pg document with ~1,000 pgf images, and it doesn't cause any problems (I wouldn't want to browse through the log, but my editor doesn't choke).  My guess would be that you have something that's adding warnings to the log file.

Comment: Perhaps you want to change your editor...

Comment: Hi my editor is TeXstudio, and I get the error "coordinate (,) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter. (see also unbounded coords=jump).". Also I will have approx 10 plots similar to this one

Comment: You might consider precompiling the `pgfplots` of `tikz` figures in separate documents, using the `standalone` class. Including them in your document with `\includegraphics` calls avoids any quality loss. Your main `tex` document will take far less time to build and errors will be much easier to spot.

Comment: ... or use `externalize`...

Comment: Hi BambOo, how would I do that? I'm sorry if this is a dumb question - I'm quite new to Latex. It seems like this may be the best solution

Comment: marmot - sorry about that its my first post! Erm may I ask how I'd use either silent or externalize?

Comment: OneDrive doesn't display the csv properly, but toward the end you have several `,,,` entries.  Could that be what's causing the error "coordinate (,) has been dropped"?  What do you intend to happen with those entries?

Comment: Hi, no so there are several data sets organised into columns - so toward the end ,,, is between data which are empty and larger sets

Comment: I think it is what @Teepeemm suggested. The error (warning actually)is about not being available to read that particular row.

Comment: Since your data is really 21 pairs of columns that aren't related to each other, you really should have 21 separate files.  If you don't want that, then the option `filter discard warning=false` is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably supposed to access this via a pgf key, but I didn't see it but you can turn off the filter logging by adding

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplots@warn@for@filter@discardsfalse
\makeatother
```

to your preamble after loading the package.

Note your example produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfk@/pgfplots/x unit ->\si 
                             {\second ^{-1}}
l.61     \end{axis}
```

But that seems unrelated.

Comment: The key is `filter discard warning=false`

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use `externalize`, i.e add

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

to the preamble of your document, see section 3.2.6 of the pgfplots manual. Then you'd have the large log file only once and also save some amount of time in the subsequent compilations.

Answer (score 2):

Your example (without `\si`) gives me a 1.4MB log file that is 26858 lines long.  26244 of those lines come from 13122 instances of the two lines

```
NOTE: coordinate (,) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter. (see also
 unbounded coords=jump).
```

So about 98% of the log's lines are because of this.

But your CSV is really many pairs of columns that just happen to be in the same file.  It's something like:

```
B18x,B18y,B16x,B16y,B14x,B14y
   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6
   7,   8,   9,  10,    ,
  11,  12,    ,    ,    ,
```

You never do anything with B18y and B16x at the same time, for example. 
 In fact, you have 20 pairs of columns, which you read into 20 different plot commands.  However, your CSV has 13122 blank coordinate pairs, which is suspiciously close to the number of warnings.

So the proper way would be to separate the different data into different files (probably within their own subdirectory, for sanity).  Then you would load B18.csv with only columns B18x and B18y, and you would load B18h.csv with only columns B18xh and B18yh.

But if you don't want to create 20 different files, you can add

```
filter discard warning=false,
```

to the axis options.  This gets the log file down to 614 lines.  The downside is that if you discard what should have been a valid point, you won't find out about it.